# Oracle Apex Background Image Display

Tags: oracle-apex

I am trying to edit the Login page for Oracle Apex Application.

```
.t-PageBody--login .t-body{
background: url(#APP_IMAGES#dataact_back.jpg)
background-size: 100% Auto;
}
```

After I've applied above CSS code in the css field, website still isn't displaying the image and I have no idea where it went wrong.

Comment: Check your browser console for errors

Comment: yeah, its a typo .t-body should be .t-Body. thanks

Comment: Ahh, I was thinking file location, but yeah - confirming you can find the selector on your page is another first step.

Answer (score 0):

Your syntax is wrong and you should try this:

```css
   .t-PageBody--login .t-body {
background: url(&APP_IMAGES.dataact_back.jpg);
background-size: 100% Auto;
}
```